# Two Android apps + web app sharing one Firebase db

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 android apps and a web app catering two user groups,

1. android app  + web app for mostly writing data to the database
2. another android app for retrieving these data

I need my applications connected to the same database, I want to know whether this is possible with Firebase and is considered valid.

I've seen older posts with workarounds but I need to know whether the new Firebase version supports this out of the box.

This is my first time trying to integrate Firebase into one of my projects therefore some guidance on achieving this task would be really useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as I can remember Firebase supported this even before the "new Firebase 2.0". Following just an excerpt taken of the [Realtime Database feature list](https://firebase.google.com/features/):

> A cloud-hosted NoSQL database. Data is stored as JSON, synced across
>   connected devices in milliseconds, and available when your app goes
>   offline.
>
> - Accessible directly from client SDKs, or from your server with the REST API

**tl;dr**
That's totally possible with Firebase.